# When I try to add a class library project I got this error: the tools version 3.5 is unrecognized

Tags: .net

When I try to add a class library project I got this error: the tools version 3.5 is unrecognized.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are on Visual Studio 2008...

Here's a fix for this:

http://execucode.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/the-tools-version-35-is-unrecognized-error-on-visual-studio-2008-startup/

Quoted from the above entry:

> Make sure these keys are present in
>   the registry. If not present add it.
>   This should resolve this issue.
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild]
>   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\3.5]
>   “DefaultToolsVersion”=”2.0″ 
>   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions]
>   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\2.0]
>   “MSBuildToolsPath”=”C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727″
>   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\3.5]
>   “MSBuildToolsPath”=”C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\”